# FPGA Synthesize - Xilinx ISE - Removing most all FF from FSM

Tags: fpga

I have a verilog module that contains an FSM.

I have extracted parts of it for this post below.

ISE XST issues warning that all the FF associated with the reg variables shown are removed and I don't understand why.

Any insights please

One of the warnings: Xst:1710 - FF/Latch  (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block . This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.

If you look below - bit 3 of RedRam_Data3 is clearly set.

```
    reg [7:0] RedRam_Data1, RedRam_Data1_next, RedRam_Data2, RedRam_Data2_next, 
             RedRam_Data3, RedRam_Data3_next, RedRam_Data4, RedRam_Data4_next;  
    reg [5:0] Stream1_Counter, Stream2_Counter, Stream3_Counter, Stream4_Counter;
    reg [6:0] Stream1_Counter_next, Stream2_Counter_next, Stream3_Counter_next, 
              Stream4_Counter_next;


    localparam Bit_1_Compare_Value = 6'd14;



    always @(posedge clk)
    begin

        RedRam_Data1 <= RedRam_Data1_next;
        RedRam_Data2 <= RedRam_Data2_next;
        RedRam_Data3 <= RedRam_Data3_next;
        RedRam_Data4 <= RedRam_Data4_next;  

        Stream1_Counter <= Stream1_Counter_next[5:0];
        Stream2_Counter <= Stream2_Counter_next[5:0];
        Stream3_Counter <= Stream3_Counter_next[5:0];
        Stream4_Counter <= Stream4_Counter_next[5:0];

    end

    always @*
    begin
        Stream1_Counter_next = Stream1_Counter;
        Stream2_Counter_next = Stream2_Counter;
        Stream3_Counter_next = Stream3_Counter;
        Stream4_Counter_next = Stream4_Counter;

        if(Diff1_Q)
            Stream1_Counter_next = Stream1_Counter + 1;

        if(Diff2_Q)
            Stream1_Counter_next = Stream2_Counter + 1;

        if(Diff3_Q)
            Stream1_Counter_next = Stream3_Counter + 1;

        if(Diff4_Q)
            Stream1_Counter_next = Stream4_Counter + 1;


        RedRam_Data1_next = RedRam_Data1;
        RedRam_Data2_next = RedRam_Data2;
        RedRam_Data3_next = RedRam_Data3;
        RedRam_Data4_next = RedRam_Data4;       


        case(FSM_State)

      SomeState:
      begin  
           if(Stream1_Counter > Bit_1_Compare_Value)
           begin 
           case(Which_Bit)
               0: RedRam_Data1_next[7] = 1'b1;
               1: RedRam_Data1_next[6] = 1'b1;
               2: RedRam_Data1_next[5] = 1'b1;
               3: RedRam_Data1_next[4] = 1'b1;
               4: RedRam_Data1_next[3] = 1'b1;
           endcase
           end // #7

           if(Stream2_Counter > Bit_1_Compare_Value)
           begin 
           case(Which_Bit)
               0: RedRam_Data2_next[7] = 1'b1;
               1: RedRam_Data2_next[6] = 1'b1;
               2: RedRam_Data2_next[5] = 1'b1;
               3: RedRam_Data2_next[4] = 1'b1;
               4: RedRam_Data2_next[3] = 1'b1;
           endcase
           end // #7

           if(Stream3_Counter > Bit_1_Compare_Value)
           begin 
           case(Which_Bit)
               0: RedRam_Data3_next[7] = 1'b1;
               1: RedRam_Data3_next[6] = 1'b1;
               2: RedRam_Data3_next[5] = 1'b1;
               3: RedRam_Data3_next[4] = 1'b1;
               4: RedRam_Data3_next[3] = 1'b1;
           endcase
           end // #7

           if(Stream4_Counter > Bit_1_Compare_Value)
           begin // #7
           case(Which_Bit)
               0: RedRam_Data4_next[7] = 1'b1;
               1: RedRam_Data4_next[6] = 1'b1;
               2: RedRam_Data4_next[5] = 1'b1;
               3: RedRam_Data4_next[4] = 1'b1;
               4: RedRam_Data4_next[3] = 1'b1;
           endcase
           end // #7
```

Comment: Did it work perfectly in all respects, in simulation? If not, synthesis may have identified opportunities for "optimisation" that you did not intend.

Comment: Simulates as expected.  The warning says that the optimizer will remove the FF which suggests to me that execution on the actual FPGA will not match simulation -- or am I wrong in that belief?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I don't do Verilog, so I can't tell if Stream3_Counter ever gets incremented; I can't see anything that would increment it. So this : " bit 3 of RedRam_Data3 is clearly set" si not at all clear to me. However if you say it simulates as you would expect, normally synth results will do exactly the same.

Comment: A Thought: RedRam_Data1 is a FF that holds a bit from a Ram Data Byte.  I am sending each bit out an output port.  The Ram Data Byte does not change during that whole process so could the optimizer just be routing the bit directly from the Data Byte and NOT perform the extra pipline stage I have in place by discreetly pulling the data bit on it's own?

Comment: A Thought. Pay attention when using the paste key.

Comment: I don't understand??????

Comment: What does this do? `        if(Diff3_Q)
            Stream1_Counter_next = Stream3_Counter + 1;` And if it does what I think it does, why didn't simulation catch it?

Comment: Diff3_Q is an input whose bit width determines if its a one or zero.  Stream counter counts how many clk cycles it is hi.  After the input goes lo, the count is compared to a constant to determine if 1 or 0.  I put only a small piece of my code since the warning stated the values were constant at zero and I was showing that they indeed changed.

Comment: OK you missed it. Read that line of code again.

Comment: Don't understand.  Code is simple FSM implemented counter.  What do you propose I missed?

Comment: It's not a counter, because it assigns to the wrong signal. Now, before you fix it, fix whatever went wrong in your testbench so that you can catch this and the other error(s) in simulation. Then try synth again.

Comment: Daugh!!!!!!! -- I only test one of the 4 inputs -- I see my mistake on the other 3.  Thanks for noting it!!!!

Comment: Thumbs UP to Brian Drummond!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

> "any insights please"

Test reasonably fully in simulation. Preferably with a self checking testbench which reports whether or not what ought to happen, actually is happening.

Almost always - as here - if synthesis is trimming away your code, it is because your code isn't actually doing anything, so it can safely be removed without affecting the result.

Proceeding to synthesis without testing reasonably well in simulation is doing things the hard way.

On quick projects I don't always test everything ... at first.

But if I see something suspicious in synth, as you did here, I revisit the testbench and add tests for it, so that

> If you look below - bit 3 of RedRam_Data3 is clearly set.

... is actually demonstrated ... and then if it isn't, further tests to reveal why not (e.g. is that counter counting?)